How to attach visual studio code to a java process on linux loading *.so files via JNI
I have the following setup on our debug machines:

wsl running Ubuntu linux,
main code is written in C++ and exposed as shared objects, compilation done using g++,
these shared objects are then loaded by a java process and main processing is done in the C++ layer,
pretty much very difficult to debug using gdb.
Debugging is mostly done via old style printing to log files. This is really, really cumbersome and I would like to be able to do this via VSCode.

Can someone suggest how to set up launch.json file to be able to do so? I am coming from windows background and debugging there on a Visual Studio is just a breeze. Not quite the same thing on linux (or wsl actually).
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
I can debug simple C++ programs but this is not quite the same thing. Attaching to another process is a different kind of beast.

You can always attach to JVM and debug your native code from there. This is not exactly the same thing as you ask, but similar example: https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU . I am pretty sure, attaching from VSCode works pretty much the same way.
